# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 from query

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to do some calculations on two tables. When I query the database directly, it retries the data. But the php request returns this error: `"Notice: Undefined offset: 0"`

this is the query:

```
    public function getTotalDatabyMonth($date, $indicateur, $restriction) {    
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('dbStat')->getConnection();
        $rawSql = "select t.cod_soc, t.tiers, t.nb_dos, coalesce(q.nb_qua,0) as nb_qua, ROUND(coalesce(q.nb_qua,0)/t.nb_dos::float*100) TOTAL"; 
        $rawSql .=" from";
        $rawSql .=" (select cod_soc, tiers, period, sum(nb_dos) as nb_dos from public.tiers_datamart group by  cod_soc, tiers, period ) t";
        $rawSql .=" left join";  

        if($indicateur != null){
            $rawSql .= " (select cod_soc, tiers, period, typ_qua,sum(nb_qua) as nb_qua  from public.quality_datamart where typ_qua='" .$indicateur."' group by cod_soc, tiers, period , typ_qua) q";
        }else{
            $rawSql .= " (select cod_soc, tiers, period, typ_qua,sum(nb_qua) as nb_qua  from public.quality_datamart group by cod_soc, tiers, period , typ_qua) q";
        }
        $condition =" where t.period = '" .$date."' ".$restriction;
        $rawSql .=" on t.cod_soc = q.cod_soc and t.tiers = q.tiers and t.period = q.period" .$condition;
        return $rawSql;
        $stmt = $em->prepare($rawSql);
        $stmt->execute();   
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
        return intval($result[0]['total']); //the error is sent here
    }
```

I tried to return `$result` but the query does not give the expected result. what is wrong in the request?

```
var_dump($result); returns ``select t.cod_soc, t.tiers, t.nb_dos, coalesce(q.nb_qua,0) as nb_qua, ROUND(coalesce(q.nb_qua,0)/t.nb_dos::float*100) TOTAL from (select cod_soc, tiers, period, sum(nb_dos) as nb_dos from public.tiers_datamart group by  cod_soc, tiers, period ) t left join (select cod_soc, tiers, period, typ_qua,sum(nb_qua) as nb_qua  from public.quality_datamart where typ_qua='NC' group by cod_soc, tiers, period , typ_qua) q on t.cod_soc = q.cod_soc and t.tiers = q.tiers and t.period = q.period where t.period = '08-2018'  AND t.cod_soc = 'QS' AND t.tiers IN ('SNF','FLOQUIPATL','AIBERIMPORT','AIRBUSHELITBY')``
```

Comment: What is in `$result`? What `var_dump($result);` show to you?

Comment: Please let me show var_dump($rawSql).

Comment: @FelippeDuarte   I can't post the result because it is very too long. Let me edit the question

Comment: try $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: If your query only returns one row, or you want only the first row, use `(int) $stmt->fetch()['total']`. In this case, your error means that `fetchAll()` did not return an array.

Comment: @Jaquarh it returns null instead of the actual data

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminetly

Comment: `return $rawSql;` <- remove this line, you can't have more than 1 return in a function. Your code stops there.